# Type-Mismatch on For Each Range

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, type-mismatch, outofrangeexception

i'm getting a type mismatch while trying to copy a range of cells. This macro needs to open 2 different workbooks, and then proceeds to copy a predefined set of cells, so the empty cell in the WorkBook(Filename1) D19, becomes the value of the already filled D19 cell in WorkBook(Filename2).
This is the complete code im working on:

```
Sub OpenWorkbooks()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim FileName1, FileName2 As String
Dim Rng, ArCell As Range

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
Dim FileChosen As Integer

FileChosen = fd.Show
fd.InitialFileName = "C:\"
fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

fd.Filters.Clear
fd.Filters.Add "Excel1", "*.xlsx"
fd.Filters.Add "Excel2", "*.xlsm"

fd.FilterIndex = 1
fd.ButtonName = "Select &2Files .xlsm/.xlsx"

If FileChosen <> -1 Then
Else

FileName1 = fd.SelectedItems(1)
Workbooks.Open (FileName1)
FileName2 = fd.SelectedItems(2)
Workbooks.Open (FileName2)

End If
```

And here comes the problematic part, the debug highlights the third line (added .address

```
    Set Rng = Range("D19,D20,I19,I20,C30,C32,C35,C36,D40,D41,D42,D43,D44,D45")
    For Each ArCell In Rng.Cells
    Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(1).Range(ArCell.**address**) = Workbooks(FileName2).Sheets(1).Range(ArCell.**address**)
    Next ArCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

edited: @PaichengWu I took your suggestion and it got rid of the type-mismatch problem, **but the subscription out of range still persists. I used this kind of Range = Range definition before and I recall it bypassing the need for an "activate" so why doesn't it work under this circumstances**

Even when trying stuff like "Workbooks(FileName1).Activate" before the operation, the debug still point out "Out of range". Sr if I'm being this dense, this is the second time in my life I've worked on vba...

Comment: Dim Rng, ArCell As Range dimensions Rng as a Variant (undefined by your syntax) and only ArCell as range. Try Dim Rng As Range, ArCell As Range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rewrite below

```
Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(1).Range(ArCell) = Workbooks(FileName2).Sheets(1).Range(ArCell)
```

as

```
Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(1).Range(ArCell.address) = Workbooks(FileName2).Sheets(1).Range(ArCell.address)
```

Comment: thanks! this certainly got rind of the mismatch, but now I'm getting a "Subscription out of range", I know I don't need to Select the open workbook to work on it, could It be I need to declare global variables? Or is it because the particular files I'm opening give me the "This workbook contains links to externals sources, do you want to update?"

Comment: Where does the `Subscription out of range` occure?  `Subscription out of range` usually occure when you refer to a workbook, worksheet, or range which do not exist.  For example, your `sheets(1)` is a chartsheet, which `sheets(1).Range(xxxx)` does not exist, may return an error.  I recommand you modity `Sheets(1)` to `Worksheets(1)`.

Comment: I just added "MsgBox fd.SelectedItems(1)" (since then we have FileName1 = fd.SelectedItems(1) )to check and its the entirety of the folder path (C: etc etc) and not only the .xlsx so every time Im doing: Workbooks(FileName1).Worksheets(1).Range(ArCell.Address) its actually just gibberish, no wonder the macro cant interact with that workbook! I guess I have to use a "set this workbook" or rather "active workbook" to some variable after I open each one to solve it?

Comment: If my answer slove your problem, please give me a `Check`.

Answer (score 0):

*Dim Rng, ArCell As Range* dimensions Rng as a Variant (undefined by your syntax) and only ArCell as range. Try *Dim Rng As Range, ArCell As Range*

The default property of a range is the *Value* property. Therefore, if you write 
*Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(1).Range(arCell) = 1*
you are assigning the value of 1 to the defined range. In order to not confuse yourself write *Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(1).Range(arCell).Value = 1*

Of course, *Workbooks(FileName1).Sheets(1).Range(arCell)* makes no sense because arCell is a range whose exact location (workbook and worksheet) is already defined. Therefore your whole long line burns down to *arCell.Value = 1*. Same for the value to be assigned except that my reduction would burn down to arCell.Value = arCell.Value which you don't have in mind. You might want to play with arCell.Address but *Address* isn't the default property, *Value* is. So, write what you mean and mean what your write.

Comment: You say arCell exact location including WS and WB is already defined, but when did I specify beforehand on the code that that was the case? thx in advance,

Comment: Here: Set Rng = Range("D19,D20,I19,I20,C30,C32,C35,C36,D40,D41,D42,D43,D44,D45"). No worksheet or workbook is specified. Therefore the range is in the ActiveSheet.

Comment: that certainly explains a lot, I thought I was just defining a pseudo-array of unspecified addresses; so if the FileName2 is the last one to open I guess i'm defining them there. Also, I don't quite understand what  "dimensions Rng as a Variant" means.

Comment: The *Dim* statement assigns a "dimension" to a variable. The variable is "dimensioned". (Sorry, English isn't my mother tongue, either, but sometimes I forget and invent things.) When you dimension a variable you assign a data type to it, like *Dim MyVar As String*. If you omit the data type from the *Dim* statement the variable is dimensioned as Variant.